# What is the list of requirements to build a webserver at home?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver

Please i am researching to check the programs and hardware devices i need to build my own webserver.

Any trusted links, ideas or solutions are highly appreciated!

Comment: This is way too broad and off-topic. If you want to learn about webservers, read the popular quests at [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to publish (static pages, large content as big images or movies, dynamic content, ...) and how much traffic (requests) you plan.

Of course the more "work" you do (dynamic pages) and the more requests you have the better the server should be. The same applies for bandwidth: if you plan to have a lot of accesses with a lot of payload you will need a good connection.

For a basic web server you will need

- any machine: to serve static pages anything in the last 5-8 years will do
- any OS (choose something you already know)
- RAM depending on the number of accesses
- a web server (e.g., Apache httpd, Apache Tomcat for Java applications, ...)

A more specific answer is only possible if you tell us what you want to do with your server. It's like asking for a car suggestion: you can go from a small one place electric car to Formula 1: depending on what you need.

**EDIT**

From your comment I see a completely different picture:

- 500'000 members means that you will have external customers or users: this means that you have a certain responsibility as in backups, redundancy, and so on. I would never have a single machine at home for a productive system with 500K users.
- Since you have members it is very likely that your web server will have some dynamic content: what are you doing? My suggestion of a simple old machine makes no sense anymore

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I am a new user here so i can't technically vote (+1) for you. I am looking forward to host a website that has around 500,000 members. Thus the traffic is around the medium level i would say.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows operating system you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or the windows version of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html). If you use a linux-based operating system you can use, among others, the linux version of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html).

For the hardware stuff, there's no specific hardware needs. A recent hardware (5-6 years old) is more than enough.

This obviously if you want to create a basic webserver. Infact if you want to create a professional one you need to have [raid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) support.

Comment: Thanks for that! How about the requirements concerning the hardware devices?

Comment: I don't really see what RAID has to do with a more or less professional web server.

Comment: @Matteo If you want to do a professional webserver with a serious service on it you MUST have a serious way to backup data (mirror RAID).

Comment: Thanks for the well structured answer! That was helpful.

Comment: RAID *does not* replace the need for backups. All a RAID does is improve data security in the running system (slightly), you still lose data if you delete it, if someone else deletes it, if a program/script deletes it, if it gets corrupted by any number of things.... in short RAID and backups have nothing to do with each other at all. also i would never mirror raid when RAID5 is so much better for data security, maybe to improve speed.

Comment: @xyious Obviously it does not replace the need for backups BUT it is easy to do, infact you can also use a software and it is surely better than have no mirror data at all.